# Sending mail with MimeKit and default email

Tags: c#, email, mimekit

I need send a mail from my program. Then I use MimeKit.
The problem is when run the program in another computer, with another email configurated by default.
So I need to use that default email on that computer.

My code is

```
        var message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("CCCC", "cccc@xxxxx.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("KKKK", "kkkkkk@jjjjj.es"));
        message.Subject = "¿Cómo estás?";

        message.Body = new TextPart("plano")
        {
            Text = @"Kaixo Lorea"
        };

        using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
```

I'm working with C# and Windows 10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you are asking how to read the SMTP server configuration settings from whatever email client program is configured on another system.

I doubt you'll have much luck with that.

Comment: Thanks. In VB6 there are a control Mapi Messages 
MSMAPI32.OCX. You knows something similar for C#

Comment: I'm not familiar with MSMAPI32.OCX, so I can't tell you if there is an equivalent to it in C# or not. What exactly does it do?